# Overload operator+ to increase IP addresses on boost::asio::ip

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, boost-asio

I would like to do math operations with IP addresses from `boost::asio`. Specifically I need to increment and/or add a given integer on an existing address to ease IP list generation in a software that I'm writing.

As today I'm using custom classes to handle IP addresses and networks, but I would like to move to `boost::asio` so I can rely on them to properly check/validade addresses and network attributes.

I have this working code as example (except for the `operator+` part):

```
using boost::asio::ip::make_address_v4;
using boost::asio::ip::address_v4;

auto add(const address_v4& address, std::size_t value = 1) {
    return make_address_v4(address.to_uint() + value);
}

// This is definitely wrong
auto operator+(std::size_t value, const address_v4& address) {
    return add(address, value);
}

int main() {
    auto ip1 = make_address_v4("192.168.1.1");
    fmt::print("IP address: {}\n", ip1.to_string());

    auto ip2 = make_address_v4(ip1.to_uint() + 1);
    fmt::print("IP address: {}\n", ip2.to_string());

    // Add function
    fmt::print("Added IP: {}\n", add(ip2, 8).to_string());
    fmt::print("Added IP: {}\n", add(ip2).to_string());

    // operator+
    fmt::print("Added IP: {}\n", (ip2 + 4).to_string());

    return 0;
}
```

`add` function works as expected, but I don't know how to overload it so I can do things like: `ip++` or `ip + 4`.

Also is there a better way to do math with `boost::asio::ip::address_v4`? I'm always getting values as `uint` and doing the math there.

Another solution that I was thinking was to inherit `boost::asio::ip::address_v4` and create the custom operators, but I don't know if this would work and if it works, this seems overkill, or even worse, I don't know if this is a good practice, it looks like it doesn't.

Thank you.

Comment: you can simply swap the parameter's order for `operator+` function to make another `operator+` overload then it'll work. 

`auto operator+(const address_v4& address, std::size_t value) {
    return add(address, value);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To technically work you need the overload:

```
// This is morally wrong
auto operator+(const address_v4& address, std::size_t value) {
    return add(address, value);
}
```

That's because the left-hand operand is `address_v4`, not `size_t`.

**[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83fd0dc9a990a07a)**

However, please don't do this. See e.g. [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421708#4421708). There is no clear and undisputed meaning of the operation here. There is much room for surprises. Depending on subnetting, incrementing an address can make a regular address into a broadcast address, or even cross over into different subnets.

E.g. `"10.10.9.254" + 0x01010101 == 11.11.10.255` makes little sense, and `"255.255.255.255" + 0x01010101 == "1.1.1.0"` even less.

What you probably want here is a subnet-aware enumerator/iterator interface, perhaps even with random sampling if you need non-sequential traversal. If you abstract this away as if `address_v4` is "just an arithmetic type" you're lying about your domain information.

Comment: Thanks @sehe, but I need to increment it anyway. operator++ would be sufficient, I do understand your reasoning and I was thinking how I could make it safe, perhaps throwing when the network is out of it's boundaries for example. A overflow check is also a good idea. The idea to overload + is to make the code more easy to read, since I'll be doing +1 in a for loop to generate a list of addresses.

Comment: Tell me, what makes it so that `++address` is okay, but `increment(address)` isn't? The "I'll be doing +1 in a for loop to generate a list of addresses" was **exactly** what made me say `What you probably want here is a subnet-aware enumerator/iterator interface`.

Comment: increment(address) is also okay. So to be clear you would recommend using a function instead and forget about overloading operator+ (and operator++).

Comment: Yes. <padding/><padding/>